# Linewidth smaller than 1

Tags: plot, gnuplot, cairo

I would like to plot these data

```
1   2
2   3
3   5
4   5
5   6
```

with this code

```
set ter pdfcairo enhanced color solid
set out "test.pdf"

set xrange [-.5:4.5]
set yrange [.5:6.5]
unset key

plot "test.txt" u 0:1,"" u 0:2, "" u 0:1:(0):($2-$1) with vectors nohead lw 0.5
```

The line width command seems to work, but it seems not to work with a line width smaller than 1.

this plot is with line width 5:

[image]

this plot is with line width 1

[image]

this plot is with line width 0.2

[image]

as one may notice, there is no difference between the latter two plots. How can I force gnuplot to use a line width smaller than 1?

Comment: Well, for me both `lw 1` and `lw 2` look pretty similar :) Consider using integer values only, or different colors if you want to clearly emphasize some features of the plot.

Comment: Is your expectation to use 20% of a pixel?

Comment: @vagoberto this is a MWE of my problem, in the plot i actually want to make, thinner lines are necessary. Other colors would only confuse the reader.

Comment: @RichC i probably want 0.2pt. But the unit does not really matter to me, hence the export file-format is vector-based. I just want thinner lines.

Comment: you could make a bigger pdf using the `size` keyword in `set term pdfcairo size ...`

Comment: @bibi that would be possible. But than i would have to re-adjust everything, like font size, frame-width, tick-width etc. pp. – 

If there is no other way, thats my only choice but i really want wo avoid that 'dirty style'.